# Adding ALL True's into one column from various columns

Tags: r

I am new to Stackoverflow AND to Rstudio. I have a question that I think is pretty basic, but I am not sure how to do it.

I am currently doing some medical research right now. I will post a picture below so you can see what I want to do. Basically, I have been looking into specific surgeries that have been done “anteriorly.” All of these specific anterior surgeries I have in columns, such as “anterior procedure #1, anterior procedure #2, anterior procedure #3.” If they have had the surgery, it is put as “TRUE.” What I want to do, is I want to “add” the “trues” on all of these surgeries into one column/ group that will be named generally- Anterior Procedures.

HOWEVER, I have tried this before, and unfortunately, it would NOT count ALL of the trues. LIke in the 3rd row below, it has counted two trues as one. The column/group I aim to create with the additions together, will be used to run a risk ratio with another variable ( I.e. specific complication with surgery).

Thus, my question is, how do I make a new “column” or “group” with ALL of the additions of the “TRUEs” in the columns I have.

I am happy to clarify too + I thank you from the bottom of my heart.

[image]

Comment: Please share a reproducible piece of your data by `dput(head(data))` so that we can use it to help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
> TRUE & TRUE
[1] TRUE
> TRUE + TRUE
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but you could use

```r
df$all_ant <- rowSums(df)
```

which gives you the number of `TRUE` values in your row. So in your case this returns

```r
  procedure_1 procedure_2 all_ant
  <lgl>       <lgl>         <dbl>
1 TRUE        FALSE             1
2 FALSE       TRUE              1
3 TRUE        TRUE              2
```

### Data

```r
df <- readr::read_table2("procedure_1 procedure_2
                         TRUE FALSE
                         FALSE TRUE
                         TRUE TRUE")
```